# Nginx + Rails 4 assets not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, http-status-code-404, assets

I've just deployed my first Rails app to production, but encountered error: my assets for some reason are not served by nginx. Assets are compiled and exist. Names are correct, paths correct. Instead of assets nginx sends me 404 error. As a server I use Puma if that matters.

My config for that part looks like this:

```
  location ~* ^/assets/ {
    # Per RFC2616 - 1 year maximum expiry
    expires 1y;
    add_header Cache-Control public;

    # Some browsers still send conditional-GET requests if there's a
    # Last-Modified header or an ETag header even if they haven't
    # reached the expiry date sent in the Expires header.
    add_header Last-Modified "";
    add_header ETag "";
    break;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the source of problems. I am using Capistrano for deploy, so in my nginx config I gave wrong root path

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
  root /var/www/my_portal/current/public;
```

I missed `current` part in the root path, cause Capistrano symlinked it to current release of my app.

Comment: thank you!!! I had already double-checked this `root` config, but somehow overlooked the `current` part...